What does "/$" mean to "grep"?
I'm using these two codes below.
ls -lap . | grep -v "/$"

ls -lap . | grep -v "/"

These two give me different outputs in some cases. What does $ mean in that context?

in this context, it's what it means in grep that matters - see for example Anchoring (GNU grep)

It's a regular expression to denote the end of a line.  This command is being used to exclude directories from the ls output since they will end with a /.  I'm not sure of a condition in which ls -lap .
output would include a / anywhere but the end of the line but if that scenario does exist the output of the two commands would not be identical.
See the following example:
$ ls -lap .
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 10:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 09:59 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 10:00 bar/
-rw-r--r--  1 jesse_b jesse_b    0 Apr 13 09:59 foo
-rw-r--r--  1 jesse_b jesse_b    0 Apr 13 10:00 oof
$ ls -lap . | grep -v "/$"
total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 jesse_b jesse_b    0 Apr 13 09:59 foo
-rw-r--r--  1 jesse_b jesse_b    0 Apr 13 10:00 oof
$ ls -lap . | grep -v "o$"
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 10:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 09:59 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 10:00 bar/
-rw-r--r--  1 jesse_b jesse_b    0 Apr 13 10:00 oof
$ ls -lap . | grep -v "o"
drwxr-xr-x  3 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 10:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 09:59 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 jesse_b jesse_b 4096 Apr 13 10:00 bar/


You should single-quote the REs so that the shell can't get at them

@ChrisDavies Many people use variables in their grep search pattern so to make a blanket statement like that might not be the best approach.  It's true that "/$" is very different from "/$f" vs '/$f' however since it's being used to match the end of the line that scenario is very unlikely.  Ultimately people just need to understand how shell escapes and expansions work to understand all the different gotchas that can occur and that is more difficult to summarize in a single rule like using single quotes.

You're using a fixed string that the shell has no need to process. Single quotes avoid unintentional issues

While one would usually need to escape dollar signs within double-quotes, there should be no issues with "/$". Even just /$ without the quotes would also work fine. As for single-quoting fixed strings as a rule..., that would mean the command here would need to be written as 'grep' '-v' '/$', and surely that's a bit excessive.

In case that's directed at me, @ilkkachu, I'm aware that "/$" won't get mangled by the shell. But by getting into the habit of putting fixed strings unto single quotes (regardless of whether they are an RE or not) one will reduce the chance of an unexpected and unwanted issue

@ChrisDavies right but in order to know when you have a fixed string or not you need to understand all of the shell escapes and expansions.  If you fully understand all the expansions that will or will not happen in your command and know which you want to allow or prevent you don't need to be told which quotes to use, but otherwise there isn't a great catch all rule.

Fixed string -> single quotes. A string that you want the shell to parse -> double quotes. I really don't see the complication

@jesse_b, it seems to me that just (single-)quoting when in doubt would avoid the need to remember the exact details of all special characters. (you would need to remember how to pass literal single-quotes, though.)

FWIW I'm on the lazy side (I don't want to figure out each time if a string may break the shell) and as a rule I single-quote any token containing a non-alphanumerical character (excluding the command itself and long / short options). Like grep --perl-regexp -v foo 'filename;that;breaks;the;shell.txt'

Regarding "to denote the end of a line" - it really denotes the end of the string that you're applying the regexp to, it just happens to coincide with the end of a line in this case because grep by default reads 1 line at a time. If you used GNU grep -z to read NUL-separated input instead of newline separate input then it'd be clear that $ didn't match the end of a line.

Regarding quotes: always use single quotes unless you NEED double quotes and then use those unless you NEED no quotes. That way you don't have to think about when you need to use single quotes, you just have to learn about the things you need to use (double quotes or no quotes) when you need them and if you make a mistake your script will fail, forcing you to learn about them.
